# Configure Apache Archiva log files

Tags: archiva

I have a server running Archiva, end the log folder is going out of controll. Archiva never deletes any log file.

How do I change configuration so it keeps logs just for the last month, or week, or keep just a maximun size?

Answer (score 1):

Archiva is using log4j2 see default configuration file here https://github.com/apache/archiva/blob/master/archiva-modules/archiva-web/archiva-webapp/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
It's included in the distribution but you can override with the sys property -Dlog4j.configurationFile=pathtoyourfile
There is an option now called CustomDeleteOnRollover for your need have look here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover